# How to transfer a class as a type through index.d.ts and module definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

I have a typescript + javascript module and it is being compiled as a package that can be imported by another project. I think it would be best to explain it with some code and then explain my question.

Shortly, how can I use my class as a type in another project when it is converted into a package?

The class that needs to be used as a type:

my-class.ts

```
export default class MyClass{
    ...
}
```

index.ts

```
import MyClass from './my-class';

export {
  MyClass,
};
```

index.d.ts

```
declare module '@package/my-project'{
    export interface MyClass{
        //Am I supposed to declares types here?
    }        
}
```

otherProjectApp.vue

```
import {MyClass} from '@package/my-project';

private myClassInstance: any; //I want this to be :MyClass instead of "any"

beforeCreate(){
    this.myClassInstance = new MyClass();
}
```

so as you can see from the simplified code snippets, I want to use MyClass as a type for my initializing in otherProjectApp.vue. It is a vue file but it isn't really important for this situation I believe.

I have been looking at the following links but, couldn't really figure out how to implement this.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

https://github.com/benjamn/ast-types/issues/106

https://medium.com/@tomsoir/typescript-how-to-rewrite-type-definition-file-file-d-ts-of-any-node-modules-package-1eed7f5630d1

To give some context, here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "./extradetails.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just set `declaration: true` and use the autogenerated `.d.ts` file?

Comment: There is also javascript files in the project and I believe that creates problems and I am using the scaffolding setup made by my company so there are some extra behind the scene details, and I also just really wanted to learn how to be able to do this. Thank you for your suggestion though, I'll try it again just to make sure